# Info on NASA's NOS3 software and the rest of the suite used by STF-1

Tags: cubesat, software, simulation

THE STF-1 cubesat project, in cooperation with NASA, has developed a whole suite of simulation software for small satellites.

Info here: http://stf1.com/simulation.php
And here: https://www.nasa.gov/centers/ivv/jstar/nos3.html

Does anyone have any info on the software stack?  The NOS3 site says it'll eventually be available as open source - does anyone know when?  And what about the rest of the components?  Is any of it available to the general public?

Thanks.

UPDATE:  I've found most of the elements (see below), but there are two "missing":  NOS3 itself, and OOPP.  OIPP sounds like something they've developed for that project, not sure if it's inteded to be public.  I'd love to see NOS3 though.  Any info on that would be welcome.

The rest of the "stack":

cFS(core Flight System) community home page is here: http://coreflightsystem.org and the source code is available here: https://github.com/nasa/cFE

42 is found here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/fortytwospacecraftsimulation/

COSMOS is here: http://cosmosrb.com/

Vagrant is here: https://www.vagrantup.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Jon McBride Software Testing and Research Lab (JSTAR) Team / Independent Test Capability (ITC) Team both created NOS3 and proposed/built/coded Simulation-to-Flight 1.

The stf1.com website has recently been updated to include a NOS3 section since the software has recently been released through NASA's Open Source release process.

The link for NOS3 is here: http://www.stf1.com/NOS3Website/Nos3MainTab.html